# Consecutive values below threshold value

Tags: r

I have a vector of approximately 1000 years of PDSI values that range from 6 to -6. I'd like to find a quick way to search when there are four or more consecutive years that are <= -2 value. Furthermore I need the data to be kept within a vector of the same length as the original 1000 so that I can plot them together. The end product could even be a logic vector. Here's an example of what I have and what I'd like.

```
Original <- c(1,6,5,-2,-6,-4,-2,0,1,-2,-3,0) 
New <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0) # expected output
```

Comment: check out something like `rle(PDSI<2)`

Comment: @BenBolker he wants `== -2` , so rle(PDSI == -2)`  maybe

Comment: OP *originally* wanted `<(-2)` (I misread, then OP edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following

```
x <- c(rep(-2, 5), rep(0, 3), rep(-2, 4), rep(0,6), rep(5, 2), rep(-2, 6), rep(-6, 2))
    (r <- rle(x))
    ##  Run Length Encoding
    ##    lengths: int [1:7] 5 3 4 6 2 6 2
    ##    values : num [1:7] -2 0 -2 0 5 -2 -6
    (r$lengths[r$lengths > 3 & r$values== -2]) # length of each sequence
    ## [1] 5 4 6
```

To get the vector with only a sequence of "-2" you can try

```
r$values[r$values != -2] <- 0
rep(r$values,  r$lengths)

##  [1] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  0  0  0 -2 -2 -2 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  0  0
```

Comment: close, but the OP wanted `== -2` , not `< -2`

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful! However is there a way to make an end product that's perhaps a logical vector being the same length as the original, but with there being only 1's where there are four (or whatever length we want) consecutive values <=-2 and the rest are zeros? Example: Original <- 1,6,5,-2,-6,-4,-2,0,1,-2,-3,0                                       New<- 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: You should edit your post to clarify what you exactly want with an example and the expected result.

Comment: You're right, i wasn't clear enough in my post and I apologize. However thank you for your help!